# Cookies and MAC in PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

Background information:
I am creating a very small and simple website that needs to allow users to log in and see pages that they are only allowed. For example if a user logs in and they are an admin they can see admin.php but if the user is not an admin, they cannot see admin.php. Cookies are used to allow the user to navigate through the pages without having to re authenticate.

A few Questions: What is the use of a MAC? How can I implement one? according to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code 
Both the client and the server have the key, how is this possible?
What about a system that generates a random session id, puts the session id in to the database (along with an expiration) and puts the session id in the cookie. Once the cookie is read it check the session id in the cookie against the one in the database which in-turn pulls up the users information (whether he is an admin or not) and if expired in the database will prompt the client to re-authenticate?

I cannot use PHP session, I must use cookies.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Use PHP session variables, not cookies.

Comment: @Barmar I modified the question, I cannot use Session, I Must use cookies.

Comment: What you're trying to implement is essentially how sessions work. PHP generates a session ID, puts it in a cookie, and uses that to find a file containing the session data.

Comment: _“I cannot use Session”_ – _why_ not?

Comment: @CBroe My project requires me to use cookies, sessions are forbidden. More or less I just need to understand good practices for using cookies to authenticate a user.

Comment: @Barmar ah, would you say it is a good Idea to implement what I described above? or is there a better way. My professor was fairly vague about MAC and how it is used in a cookie. For example: how would the client and server use the same key?

Comment: I don't know, it sounds like a question that's better asked on security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To “forbid sessions” when the implementation of a login system is required is just stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using cookies you can use sessions. This is the preferred method for sessions anyways. You will store the session ID in the cookie. [The article on Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) describes the role of cookies in the mitigation part quite well.

A MAC is a method to authenticate messages (as the name implies). But it requires that you can exchange the keys securely. It won't help you in your specific case.

You are probably interested in [HMAC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)s. A brief explanation:

Bob and Alice have a shared key. Alice wants to send a message to Bob. Note that the message itself can be public. But Bob wants to be sure that the message is indeed from Alice. So Alice needs to *sign* the message. So Alice takes the message, signs it through HMAC with the secret key and sends the message along with the resulting signature to Bob.

When Bob receives the message he does the same as Alice did when signing the message. He takes the message, signs it with the secret and compares the signatures.

If the signatures match Bob can be pretty sure that the message has not been tampered with. It is *authentic*. If on top of that Bob can be pretty sure that no one other than Alice has access to the key, he can also assume that the message was indeed sent by Alice.

Extracting the secret from the signature is very hard (the H-Part of HMAC takes care of that). The MAC makes sure that it is hard to tamper with the messages even if you collected a lot of messages between Bob and Alice (along with some other attack methods).

Sometimes you will see some people just using a hash function to create signatures. Use [HMAC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).